# Как в android получить время с интернет?

Tags: android

Какую библиотеку нужно использовать чтоб получить время с какого-то сервера
или метод

Comment: Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, то Вы можете принять его как верный. В противном случае опишите то, что вызывает Вас сомнения или проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать библиотеку `Apache Commons Net` для получения времени через NTP сервер. Для Gradle:

```
compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
```

И использовать данный метод:

```
public Date getCurrentDate(){
    Date date = new Date();
    try{
        String timeServer = "0.pool.ntp.org";

        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(timeServer);
        TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        long time = timeInfo.getMessage().getReceiveTimeStamp().getTime();

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
        date = cal.getTime();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

P.S. в данном методе есть преобразование из типа `Calendar` в тип `Date`, что является не совсем очевидным моментом. Его можно устранить, возвращая просто `Calendar`. Это было сделано только для моего случая, т.к. я взял метод из своего приложения.