# Как получить время с ntp сервера android?

Tags: android, время, ntp

Пытаюсь получить время с ntp сервера, но почему-то получаю только текущее время устройства. Взял этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657168/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-android-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82/657169#657169).

```
public Calendar getCurrentDate(){
        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        try{
            String timeServer = "0.pool.ntp.org";

            NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(timeServer);
            TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
            long time = timeInfo.getMessage().getReceiveTimeStamp().getTime();
            Log.i("m", String.valueOf(time)+" " + timeInfo);

            cal.setTimeInMillis(time);

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cal;

    }
```

а в итоге получаю:

```
1552491732 1552491732
```

где первое число это то что вернул метод /1000 , а второе число - `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000`
Перелопатил уже кучу литературы и источников, но у меня программа упорно мне дает время на устройстве, а не текущее время timestamp. Не могу понять что не так делаю. Вроде все сделал так как в ответе. Если у кого-то есть рабочий способ как получить время и дату в ntp сервера, то буду очень признателен если поделитесь :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что я сделал, чтобы получить время ntp сервера:

1. Нашел либу - `implementation 'com.github.medavox:MuTime:0.5'`
2. Сделал класс:

   ```
   class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();

       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           //optionally enable the disk cache
           MuTime.enableDiskCaching(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));//this hardens MuTime against clock changes and reboots

           try {
               MuTime.requestTimeFromServer("time.google.com");
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           try {
               long theActualTime = MuTime.now();//throws MissingTimeDataException if we don't know the time

           } catch (MissingTimeDataException e) {
               Log.i("m", "failed to get the actual time:+e.getMessage()");
           }
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Вызываю класс:

   ```
   mt = new MyTask();
   mt.execute();
   ```
4. Получаю время)

Может кому-то пригодится.