# Как получить текущее время не по системе, а из интернета в Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Делаю андроид приложение. Есть переменная curTime, туда нужно поместить timestamp по типу `1616572689`
и для этого я использовал два метода

```
val curTime: Long = Date().getTime()
```

и

```
val curTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

но проблема в том, что если я на телефоне изменю время, например 2007-ой год, то в curTime будет 2007-ой год, по этому мне нужен метод который возьмет время из интернета как нибудь, помогите кто нибудь, кто знает?

Comment: обратиться к любому серверу, который выдает точное время

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такое понятие как NTP протокол. Если взять определение данного вида протоколов с [Википедии (например)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTP) то можно увидеть такое определение:

> NTP (англ. Network Time Protocol — протокол сетевого времени) —
> сетевой протокол для синхронизации внутренних часов компьютера с
> использованием сетей с переменной латентностью. Протокол был
> разработан Дэвидом Л. Миллсом, профессором Делавэрского университета,
> в 1985 году. Версия на 2015 год — NTPv4

Как вам уже сказали в комментариях - для решения вашей задачи стоит просто обратится к серверу который предоставит вам точное время в мире. Вот например есть [такое решение](https://github.com/aslamanver/sntp-client-android) на Github:

```
SNTPClient.getDate(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo"), new SNTPClient.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeReceived(String rawDate) {
        // rawDate -> 2019-11-05T17:51:01+0530
        Log.e(SNTPClient.TAG, rawDate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception ex) {
        Log.e(SNTPClient.TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
});
```

на выходе вы получите время с сервера. [Вот здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/device/TimeManager) предоставлена документация по TimeManager Android. [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956016/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%81-ntp-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-android) есть подобный вопрос, но с решением для примера куда копать.